# How to add custom border and transparent background to ionic letter avatar

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am trying to add transparent background in my ionic letter-avatar,
but when letter avatar renders it is coming with default color background,

Here is my code:-

```
// avatar library
 <script src="lib/ionic-letteravatar-master/ionic-letteravatar.js"></script>

<ionic-letter-avatar data="{{loginUser.name}}" shape="round" avatarborder="true"></ionic-letter-avatar>
```

assuming:- `loginUser.name = Peter`

Output is coming in round shape with text **P** with some default color.

My question is how to set ionic-letter-avatar with transparent background having `solid:black` border.
So that letter **P** will come with

- round shape
- custom border with black color
- background transparent

**Edit** :-

we can add `avatarcustomborder` for customize the border

```
avatarcustomborder="border:5px solid black"
```

The problem is only, how to make background transparent.

Comment: The ionic-letteravatar library had not given any option to customize background color.

Comment: I did't get anything to change color in letter-avatar library, and I have to make it transparent instead of giving any color.
is it possible ?

Comment: In ionic-letteravatar.js library the svg element is created and the background-color has been set in getImgTag function , you can check the library code.